# Find the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that $abc=108$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that $abc=108$.

I have written $$108=3\times3\times3\times2\times2,$$ and I know that one of the two 2's have three choices, so as one of the three 3's but how can I go further in this approach?

Comment: Hint: Write $a=2^{a_2}3^{a_3}$ and similarly for $b,c.$

Comment: is the answer is 54 by any chance? please approve so I can show you my way of solving

Comment: No the answer is 60.

Comment: Can anyone help me how to solve it by multinomial.

Answer (score 1):

Now you are looking into [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $2$ and $3$ into three parts.  These are few enough you can list the by hand.  One composition of $2$ is $(0,0,2)$ which corresponds to factors $(2^0,2^0,2^2)=(1,1,4)$.  Count the number of compositions of $2$ and multiply by the number of compositions of $3$ because the factors of $2$ and $3$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = 2^{x_1}3^{y_1}$, $b = 2^{x_2}3^{y_2}$, and $c = 2^{x_3}3^{y_3}$.  Since 
$abc = 2^{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}3^{y_1 + y_2 + y_3} = 108 = 2^23^3$ and the exponents for each prime must agree,
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 2 \tag{1}$$
and
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 3 \tag{2}$$
Equations 1 and 2 are equations in the nonnegative integers.

How many solutions does the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = k \tag{3}$$
have in the nonnegative integers?

A particular solution of equation 3 in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in a row of $k$ ones.

For instance, if $k = 10$ and $n = 4$, we must insert $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs into a row of $10$ ones.  The choice
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 4$, while 
$$1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 5$, $x_4 = 3$.

Hence, the number of solutions of equation 3 is the number of ways $n - 1$ addition signs can be placed in a row of $k$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$
since we must choose which $n - 1$ of the $k + n - 1$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs to fill with addition signs.

The answer to your question can be found by multiplying the number of solutions of equation 1 (the number of ways of distributing the powers of $2$ to the three factors) by the number of solutions of equation 2 (the number of ways of distributing the powers of $3$ to the three factors).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: count the number of ways to distribute the three $3$'s among the factors
and the number of ways to distribute the two $2$'s, using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), and multiply.

Comment: Can yo please do it for me i am a beginner.

Comment: What part of the solution do you not understand? Have you tried working it out from here and where are you stuck? You will learn better by including your own attempts.

Comment: Ihave tried as follows 108=3×3×3×2×2 so the two 2's can go in 3C2 ways and 2×2=4 can go in 3C1 ways .Also3×3×3 can go in 3C3 ways ,3×3×3 can be written as 9×3 which can go in 3C2×2! ways and 3×3×3=27 can go in 3C1 ways .so the total no of ways is (3C2+3C1)(3C3+3C2×2!+3C1)=6×10 =60. Am i right , please approve.